# Does Oracle Cloud provide extended support for Databases like Oracle 11gR2 which has reached end of support

Tags: database-migration, subscription, oracle11gr2, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, end-of-life

I wanted to know if Oracle 11gR2 database is migrated to Oracle cloud without upgrading the version, then does oracle cloud provide us with extended support, as oracle 11gR2 is reaching end of support on Dec 2020.
I found 4 methods for migrating Oracle 11gR2 to Oracle cloud 11gR2 database, But I am not sure if Oracle cloud provides extension period for expiring database.

Comment: This question is about Oracle's business practices surrounding this software, not about how to use it in the context of programming. Ask your Oracle account manager.

Comment: @duskwuff I have been working for an organisation and they gave me this assignment of finding different options to deal with databases reaching end of support.

Answer (score 0):

If you adopt a Bring Your Own License approach, then **I think** you will be as you should be covered as part of your existing support agreement. I presume you're on a sustaining support agreement (https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Cloud/2068368_1.html) Your Oracle account manager will be able to confirm.

Have you considered using the use of OCI as an opportunity to move to autonomous - free yourself from patching and security considerations?